# JS+CSS How to display images from an array from top right to bottom left

Tags: javascript, css, image, sequence

I am trying to align an array of images in the following sequence:

```
13 | 10 | 7 | 4 | 1
14 | 11 | 8 | 5 | 2
   | 12 | 9 | 6 | 3
```

I have used cssFloat in js to make the sequence displaying from right to left but I do not know how to make it show 3 images in a column. May I ask if anyone might know the possible way to make it show in the sequence I desire please?

```
function loadImagesInSequence(images){
    if(!images.length){
    return;
    }

    var img = new Image(),
        url = images.shift();

    img.onload = function(){loadImagesInSequence(images)};
    img.src = url;
    img.style.width = "10%";
    img.style.cssFloat = "right";

    document.body.appendChild(img);

}

loadImagesInSequence([
'imgs/sample_2016-04-29-23-00-29-794.png',
'imgs/sample_2016-05-04-17-49-17-927.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-04-17-59-00-325.png',
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-28-02-630.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-37-26-939.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-47-37-141.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-06-15-130.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-07-57-144.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-10-49-457.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-35-27-171.png'
]);
```

Comment: Always 14 images? Always 5 columns and 3 rows?

Comment: @Tigger I actually have more than 108 images, so there should be 36 columns, however, I realised once the number of columns is bigger than the screen size, it will shrink/move below the first 3 rows (which is something I do not want). I would like it to be like an extendable horizontal scroll...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: This is major re-write based on changed info.

This will place a max of 3 images in a column, then add another to the left until all images are used up. The number of columns will vary.

```
<body>
<div id="box" style="overflow:auto;white-space:nowrap;text-align:right"></div>
<script>
function loadImagesInSequence(images) {
    var count = 0, html = '', iBlock = ''; 
    var i, len = images.length;
    for(i = 0;i < len;i++) {
        iBlock += '<img src="'+ images[i] +'" title="['+ i +']" style="display:block;width:100%" />';
        count++;
        if (count == 3) {
            if (i != (len - 1)) {
                html = '<div style="display:inline-block;width:10%;vertical-align:top">'+ iBlock +'</div>'+ html;
                iBlock = '';
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    if (iBlock != '') {
        html = '<div style="display:inline-block;width:10%;vertical-align:top">'+ iBlock +'</div>'+ html;
    }
    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = html;
}

loadImagesInSequence([
'imgs/sample_2016-04-29-23-00-29-794.png',
'imgs/sample_2016-05-04-17-49-17-927.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-04-17-59-00-325.png',
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-28-02-630.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-37-26-939.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-47-37-141.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-06-15-130.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-07-57-144.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-10-49-457.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-35-27-171.png']);
```

```js
function loadImagesInSequence(images) {
    var count = 0; html = '', iBlock = ''; 
    var i; len = images.length;
    for(i = 0;i < len;i++) {
        iBlock += '<img src="'+ images[i] +'" title="image:['+ i +']" style="display:block;width:100%" />';
        count++;
        if (count == 3) {
            if (i != (len - 1)) {
                html = '<div style="display:inline-block;width:10%;vertical-align:top">'+ iBlock +'</div>'+ html;
                iBlock = '';
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    if (iBlock != '') {
        html = '<div style="display:inline-block;width:10%;vertical-align:top">'+ iBlock +'</div>'+ html;
    }
    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = html;
}

loadImagesInSequence([
'imgs/sample_2016-04-29-23-00-29-794.png',
'imgs/sample_2016-05-04-17-49-17-927.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-04-17-59-00-325.png',
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-28-02-630.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-37-26-939.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-47-37-141.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-06-15-130.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-07-57-144.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-10-49-457.png', 
'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-35-27-171.png']);
```

```html
<div id="box" style="overflow:auto;white-space:nowrap;text-align:right"></div>
```

Comment: I actually have more than 108 images, so there should be 36 columns, however, I realised once the number of columns is bigger than the screen size, it will shrink/move below the first 3 rows (which is something I do not want). I would like it to be like an extendable horizontal scroll...

Comment: Updated the answer based on the extra info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.splice()`, `for` loop

```
function loadImagesInSequence(images) {
  if (!images.length) {
    return;
  }
  var curr = images.splice(0, 3);
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.style.height = "30px";
      div.style.width = "30px";
      div.style.display = "inline-block";
  for (var i = 0; i < curr.length; i++) {
    (function(n) {
      var img = new Image(),
        url = curr[n];
      img.src = url;
      img.width = "10%";
      div.style.cssFloat = "right";

      div.appendChild(img);
      div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }(i))
  }
  loadImagesInSequence(images)

}

loadImagesInSequence([
  'imgs/sample_2016-04-29-23-00-29-794.png',
  'imgs/sample_2016-05-04-17-49-17-927.png',
  'imgs/sample_2016-05-04-17-59-00-325.png',
  'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-28-02-630.png',
  'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-37-26-939.png',
  'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-15-47-37-141.png',
  'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-06-15-130.png',
  'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-07-57-144.png',
  'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-10-49-457.png',
  'imgs/sample_2016-05-08-16-35-27-171.png'
]);
```

```js
function loadImagesInSequence(images) {
  if (!images.length) {
    return;
  }
  var curr = images.splice(0, 3);
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.style.height = "90px";
      div.style.width = "30px";
      div.style.display = "block";
      
  for (var i = 0; i < curr.length; i++) {
    (function(n) {
      var text = document.createElement("span");
      text.style.display = "block";
      text.textContent = curr[n];
      text.style.border = "1px solid #000";
      text.style.margin = "1px";
      var img = new Image();
      //  url = curr[n];
      // img.src = url;
      // img.width = "10%";
      div.style.cssFloat = "right";

      div.appendChild(text);
      div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }(i))
  }
  loadImagesInSequence(images)

}

loadImagesInSequence([
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6',
  '7',
  '8',
  '9',
  '10',
  '11',
  '12',
  '13',
  '14'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking 2 things, how to group items based on their order in an array and how to structure them in HMTL.

Separating the items into a groups of 3 can simply be accomplished with the modulus operator (`%`) that returns the remainder of an integer after fitting a number in as many times as possible, AKA recognizing when it's a multiple of something.

Recursively print out an array and watch for when the index hits a multiple of 3 like so:

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if i % 3 == 0 {
    // move on to new group using HTML, I'll let you figure this out
  }
}
```

Now, grouping these items into vertical columns with HTML and CSS can be accomplished in a bunch of different ways. The first thing that comes to mind is using a `table`, but I think that's weird and redundant.

I'd recommend making the images block elements so that they each get their own line, wrapping the groups of 3 in a div container and finally wrapping the `div`s in a flexbox that aligns the items to the right. Like so:

```
<div id="#images">
  <div>
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <img src="2.jpg">
    <img src="3.jpg">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="4.jpg">
    <img src="5.jpg">
    <img src="6.jpg">
</div>
etc...
</div>

#images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#images img {
  display: block;
}
```

How's that for an explanation? Sorry if it sounds kind of obtuse and unassuming... I'm getting used to this StackOverflow thing. I'll be back with a better explanation and a CodePen example if you'd like :)